# scaling of results: the comparing of osm-files for a few days - a statistical approach

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, web-mapping, linux

i am pretty new to Geographic-information Systems.

i am interested in gathering information on schools Some days before i have heard that it is interesting to have a closer look at the taginfo-site (see below):

What does this mean https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=school

here we have two requests on the above site:

**a. yesterday: 2014-06-23 23:58 UTC**

```
Type count Objekts all 

**all:**  592672 0.02% -

[Node] Node 325997 - 0.36%
[Way] Way 260585 - 0.11%
[Relation] Relation 6090 - 0.23%
```

**b. some (guess two or three) days before:** we have had the following values:

```
countl Objekte all: 592 443 0.02%

[Node] Node 325 974 0.36%
[Way] Way 260 384 0.11%
[Relation] Relation 6 085 0.23%
```

see the **details:**

today all:  **592672** 0.02% -
some days before: countl Objekte all: **592 443** 0.02%

you see: that differs: we have a differende of 229 x (entries, records or some what)

Does this mean that there is a total growth of records of schools or that some records have been changed!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the true increase of school entries in the database. It has increased from 592443 to 592672. That's 0,04% increase, and can be considered as normal.

Keep an eye on the time stamp in the upper right corner: at present time, you still see the count from last night.

It might be that someone has retagged some `building = school` to `amenity = school`, which is the more common usage.

Comment: hello dear Andre: Many thanks for the quick reply. As i understand you: These increase in numbers does not rely on corrections or (re-)edits of allready existing records and entries. These difference is the true increase or the absolute count of entries.... - many thanks for the hints. greetings